# Db2 error : SQL0901N, SQLSTATE=58004

Tags: db2

Can i use Atomic in the parrent procedure as well as in the procedure which the mail procedure calls.

My procedure compiles perfectly, but sometimes when I execute it. I receive following error:

DB2 Database Error: ERROR [58004] [IBM][DB2/NT64] SQL0901N The SQL statement failed because of a non-severe system error. Subsequent SQL statements can be processed. (Reason "Sdir len bad: 1542!=1520+14".) SQLSTATE=58004

However, surprisingly when i commented the "ATOMIC" keyword in the main procedure and ran again it ran perfectly. But when I ran it again after uncommenting it still did not give any errors and ran perfectly.

So the error that I recieve is not something that I recive everytime.Could some one please let me know what could be the issue and what needs to be done to resolve this. As on goolgeing I did not find any leads on this.

Thanks,
Harveer

Answer (score 1):

Found the following statement from an IBM employee on [DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=180115). Not sure if this helps.

> > 3 In running rebind of all packages , I get an error
> >
> > "SQL0901N The SQL statement failed because of a non-severe system
> >     error.
> >     Subsequent SQL statements can be processed. (Reason "Sdir len bad:
> >     1171!=1160+9".) SQLSTATE=58004"
> >     SQLSTATE 58004: A system error (that does not necessarily preclude the
> >     successful execution of subsequent SQL statements) occurred."
> >
> > How do we identify which stored procedure,function is creating this
> >     error?
>
> SQL0901 means: call IBM. There is
>   nothing you can do about this (only
>   work around it, possibly).